# What's the appropriate way to create an alias question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070600/why-has-the-behavior-of-input-type-date-changed". At the time I thought the issue was a behavior issue, but now know it's a *display* issue. The original question is still useful, as others looking for this conversation may search for "behavior".

That said, I realize it would be useful to alias the same question as "Why has the **display** of `input type="date"` changed?". **What's the appropriate way to create such an "alias" question?** I suppose I could start a new question, then flag it as a duplicate, but is that optimal? I've read https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/, so I understand that there should be no prejudice against duplicates, still...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it will be usefull to create a new question, mark it as duplicate and let it review by 4 people for just one word difference.

I recommend you to change the title to include both words, something like *Why has the behaviour/display of `input type="date"` changed?*
Or don't change anything, because the word "*display*" is already used 11 times on that page, meaning that Google will definitely mark that as an important keyword.

Comment: So "there is no appropriate way to create an alias question"?

Comment: I don't there is one.